# Most elegant way to extract block by skipping every 2 element

Tags: rebol, red

Let's say I have

```
block: [a 1 b 2 c 3]
```

I want

```
[1 2 3]
```

Something like this is clunky and it doesn't work because I use word type (I'd like to have it word with word not string):

```
  block: [a 1 b 2 c 3]
  block2: []

  counter: -1
  foreach 'element block [
    counter: negate counter
    if counter append block2 element
  ]
```

Comment: Aside from the EXTRACT function (see below), once again your workaround solution would look more elegant with COLLECT: `collect [foreach [key value] block [keep value]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EXTRACT function should fit the bill here:

```
>> extract/index [a 1 b 2 c 3] 2 2
== [1 2 3]
```

It's fairly versatile for this type of thing.

```
>> help extract
USAGE:
     EXTRACT series width

DESCRIPTION: 
     Extracts a value from a series at regular intervals. 
     EXTRACT is a function! value.

ARGUMENTS:
     series       [series!] 
     width        [integer!] "Size of each entry (the skip)".

REFINEMENTS:
     /index       => Extract from an offset position.
        pos          [integer!] "The position".
     /into        => Provide an output series instead of creating a new one.
        output       [series!] "Output series".
```